# Can I specify the order to execute validation decorators with class-validator?

Tags: typescript, validation, class-validator

Let's say one has a class, `Post`, that one wants to validate.

```
export class Post {
  @IsArray()
  tags: string[];
}
```

Let's now say that he wants to ensure that the word 'mistake' never appears in the `tags` field. He writes a custom validation decorator to do this:

```
export function NoMistakes (validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'noMistakes',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate (tags: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          tags.forEach(tag => {
            if (tag == 'mistake') {
              return false;
            }
          });

          return true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now, he rewrites `Post` as so:

```
export class Post {
  @IsArray()
  @NoMistakes()
  tags: string[];
}
```

The problem occurs, for example, when tags in not of type `int`. In this case, an error occurs in the custom validator when trying to iterate over something that is not an array.

How can one have the validator `@IsArray` be executed before the custom validator? In general, is there a way one can choose the order of the validations?

Comment: decorators are executed in the `reverse` order: @A @B target => @A(@B(target))
in your code you clearly using some validation framework, so result order of execution is governed by it

Answer (score 9):

Typescript decorator order follows: [see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition)

1. The expressions for each decorator are evaluated top-to-bottom.
2. The results are then called as functions from bottom-to-top.

That means `class-validator` checks validation decorator bottom-to-top
So, you can edit your `Post` class like this.

```js
export class Post {
  @NoMistakes() // 2nd
  @IsArray() // 1st
  tags: string[];
}
```

And you can give `stopAtFirstError` options to skip `@NoMistakes()` when `@IsArray` makes an error.
get more informations about validator options:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator#passing-options